# Connected-springs model for Lagrangian on a 4-vector field (wave equation)

Tags: lagrangian-formalism

**Context for my question**

The 1+1 wave equation is often modeled as connected springs (or a string with tension) where the deflection $\varphi$ is transverse ($z$, another spatial dimension). Similarly, the 2+1 (scalar-valued) wave equation is often modeled as a trampoline, a 2d grid of springs in $(x,y)$ that deflect in $z.$ For 3+1 (scalar valued) we could imagine a 3d grid of springs deflecting into an embedding dimension.

The Lagrangian density and the PDE for the 3+1 case would be

$$\mathcal{L} = \varphi_{,t}^2-\varphi_{,x}^2-\varphi_{,y}^2-\varphi_{,z}^2$$
$$\square^2\varphi=0$$

To model the Lagrangian itself with springs, we could include negative springs for $t$ and add a dimension. For example, the 1+1 Lagrangian would be a 2d grid of springs. $\varphi$ would still have a deflection normal to the grid.

So in n+1 dimensions we would have n+1 springs at each grid point.

**A spring model for a 4-vector-valued wave equation**

Instead of a scalar $\varphi$ let's have a 4-vector field $A^\mu$, for example the EM 4-potential in the Lorenz gauge.

The Lagrangian density and the PDE for the 3+1 case would be

$$\mathcal{L}=A_{\mu,\nu}A^{\mu,\nu}$$
$$\square^2A^\mu=0$$

$\mathcal{L}$ now has 16 terms. That could be modeled with 16 springs at each grid point, treating each $A^\mu$'s four components as a scalar field, and four independent 4d grids coexisting neighborly.

**The question**

I find the four interlocking grids to be ugly and hope that there is a more elegant model.

For example, instead of deflecting into an embedding dimension, could we use the existing 4 dimensions for deflections (like for longitudinal waves in the 1+1 wave equation)? Could we then use just four springs per grid point?

I don't get this particular case to work out mathematically: for $x$-oriented springs the $x$ deflection results in more spring stretching than the a deflection in $y,z,t$ (for the same spring), *etc.*

Comment: I suppose that I am attached to the springs picture.
I'm in search of powerful visualizations, that is analogous systems that obey the same math.